# What determines in this code what is sent back to the client? TCP Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

In the code below, what determines what will be sent back to the client (the PHP page). I am trying to alter this so that it sends a variable back to the PHP page with an error message that is defined based on actions made in my java code.

Edit: To answer some questions, what I am trying to do is this.

Send a string to the java script with a socket and convert it to a variable to be used in the java script. It will run through some if statements and I need to set the error statements to a variable lets say "reply". I need to send "reply" then back to the PHP file.

```
public class MyJavaServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int port = 20222;
ServerSocket listenSock = null; //the listening server socket
Socket sock = null;             //the socket that will actually be used for communication

try {

   listenSock = new ServerSocket(port);

   while (true) {       //we want the server to run till the end of times

       sock = listenSock.accept();             //will block until connection recieved

       BufferedReader br = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
       BufferedWriter bw = 
          new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
       String line = "";
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           bw.write("PHP said: " + line + "\n");
           bw.flush();
       }

       //Closing streams and the current socket (not the listening socket!)
       bw.close();
       br.close();
       sock.close();
   }
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Currently it's effectively just an echo server.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, the line where the answer gets sent to the peer is

```
bw.write("PHP said: " + line + "\n");
```

which writes the given string to `bw`.

Comment: On my PHP side though the response is sent with $sock:     $reply = socket_read($sock, 10000, PHP_NORMAL_READ) //Reading the reply from socket

Comment: And that means? If I get it right, said PHP code exactly reads what is written with `bw.write()`.

Comment: I don't understand where its sending back the data and the comment above this makes about 0 sense. So I could set in the code lets say correct = "correct" and if I do bw.write(correct) it would be sending back the text "correct" which is inside the variable correct?

Comment: Exactly, that's how it works. And if you derive the variable content from whatever and send that, exactly that is sent.

Comment: @Snwspeckle The response is *received* with `socket_read(...)`.

Comment: @Snwspeckle Glad I could help. An accept and an upvote would be quite kind :-)